# rsync slow via 100Mb/s ethernet

Tags: networking, server, rsync, file-sharing, file-server

I have a file server running Ubuntu 16.04 with my entire music library, which is ~300GB, on it. I am using samba to share this media library via the local network.

I also have a Macbook that I keep a local copy of this media library on, and I rsync it from the file server to my Macbook like so:

```
rsync -av --delete /Volumes/2TB-Server/iTunes /Volumes/500GB\ HDD/iTunes/
```

Where `/Volumes/2TB-Server` is my file server and `/Volumes/500GB\ HDD/` is my local hard disk in the Macbook. However, when using `rsync` like above, I am only transferring at around 7-8Mb/s. This is all over a 100Mb ethernet network. The hard drives aren't possibly the bottleneck because I also occasionally use an external USB3.0 HDD to transfer data between these two systems (again using `rsync`) and it is very fast - around 50-60MB/s.

Why is this happening? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How did you measure the transfer speed? Are you sure it is `7-8Mb/s`and not `7-8MB/s`? (which would be OK with 100Mbit LAN)

Comment: @ridgy Wow, this may be all it was... I'm feeling pretty stupid now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a local network... it's odd that it would be that slow. Try providing the `z` flag to your rsync, which should enable compression during transfer and speed it up a little bit.